# Why does Dovecot LDA create subfolders for address detail?

Tags: email-server, dovecot, sieve

I recently noticed that my dovecot LDA creates a subfolder in my Maildir for mails that have a details part in the recipient address (local-part+detail@domain).

I absolutely cannot find a setting that would cause that. I have set "recipient_delimiter" in both 15-lda.conf and 90-sieve.conf.
I don't have any such rule in the user sieve files, either.

How do I turn it off?

Dovecot version is 2.2.33.2 (d6601f4ec).

The logs say

```
status=sent (delivered to command: /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -c /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf -m "${EXTENSION}")
```

Comment: What MTA do you use ? If it is Postfix, "recipient_delimiter = +" is set ?

Comment: Yes, I use Postfix, and the delimiter is set there, too. The logs say 'status=sent (delivered to command: /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -c /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf -m "${EXTENSION}")'
Delivery also works in general. When one of my rules with fileinto hits, the mail is delivered correctly. If no rule hits, however, the detail string is interpreted as a folder, with dots creating subsubfolders. (me+example.net@example.org ends up in example/net)

Comment: The log line is an important part of your question, please add it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By your comment above, I deduce that you configured Postfix as follows:

```
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -m "${EXTENSION}"
```

The [`-m` option](https://linux.die.net/man/1/deliver) is used to deliver the e-mail to the `${EXTENSION}` (Postfix's for detail) mailbox instead of `INBOX`. You probably want something like this instead:

```
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f "$SENDER" -a "$RECIPIENT"
```

In this way your filters can still use the envelope addresses, but the unmatched messages go to `INBOX` as intended.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!